# Isolated scope directive in ng-repeat not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having one isolated scoped directive and clear button looping in ng-repeat.

**HTML**

```
Controller (parent scope):
<br /> kids: {{kids}}
<br /> lonelyKid: {{lonelyKid}}
<br />
<hr /> Directive (ng-repeat):
<br />
<div ng-repeat="k in kids">
    <button ng-click="communicator.clear()">Clear Data</button>
    <kid k="k" communicator="communicator"></kid>
</div>
<hr /> Directive (not ng-repeat):
<br />
<button ng-click="communicator.clear()">Clear Data</button>
<kid k="lonelyKid" communicator="communicator"></kid>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("kid", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="k.name"><br>{{k.name}}<br>',
        scope: {
            k: "=",
            communicator: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.k = angular.copy($scope.k);
            $scope.communicator.clear = function() {
                console.log($scope.k)
                $scope.k.name = ''
                console.log($scope.k)
            }
        }
    };
});
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.kids = [{
        name: "Ang",
        age: 15
    }, {
        name: "Ying",
        age: 14
    }, {
        name: "Ellie",
        age: 2
    }, {
        name: "Smith",
        age: 10
    }];
    $scope.lonelyKid = {
        name: "Ming",
        age: 9
    };
    $scope.communicator = {};
});
```

When, I clicked on clear button respective directive content should get clear. But in my code, If I clicked on first element's clear button then it is clearing last element data in ng-repeat rather than first element. Same if we click on 2nd, 3rd or clear button which is not there in loop, it clears last element of loop.

Please tell me, Why this is happening? and how can I solve this problem?

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/O8emQf?p=preview)

Comment: Can you explain what `communicator` is supposed to do? Also this line looks suspicious: `$scope.k = angular.copy($scope.k);` and is probably the cause of the issue you describe.

Comment: I want to call directive function from template which is outside the directive. i.e controller and isolated directive communication. communicator is used for that only. And angular.copy is for avoiding two way data binding. I don't think angular.copy is causing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you only have one `communicator`, and its `clear` function gets overridden every time you declare a directive. So the `clear` function being called is the last one you set, in your case, the last element of the list.

By using `communicator: "="` in the `scope` property of your directive, it means you have a two-way binding for `communicator` between your controller and your directive. In other words, using `$scope.communicator` in your controller or in your directive refers to the same object.

A way to fix this could be to have one communicator per kid (although it's maybe not the best solution in terms of design, as I don't really understand the purpose of this communicator object).

See [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mzgGzqU3t7A7jmtdjGtr?p=preview) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try that instead:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.communicator.clear = function(kid) {
    kid.name = '';
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="k in kids">
    <button ng-click="communicator.clear( k )">Clear Data</button>
    <kid k="k" communicator="communicator"></kid>
</div>
<hr /> Directive (not ng-repeat):
<br />
<button ng-click="communicator.clear( lonelyKid )">Clear Data</button>
<kid k="lonelyKid" communicator="communicator"></kid>
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tGcGQeWsEPtoSgRVumYQ?p=preview)